# Convert MySql query to sql server 2019 query

Tags: mysql, sql

I think that I am close, here is what I managed so far.

```
SELECT session.id  7 day
```

The error is somesure.Please help?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent in SQL Server uses `dateadd()`:

```
session.timestamp >= dateadd(day, -7, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below, sql server does not have interval

```
SELECT session.id 
FROM session WHERE id = 1 AND customerid = 1 
AND session.timestamp >= getdate() - 7 
AND session.expired = 0
```

Comment: @Stefanie you can check and you will get the answer